# Is there any media player that can browse Shoutcast streams?

Tags: streaming, music, music-player

I read that `exaile`, `banshee` (`banshee-extension-liveradio`), and `VLC` previously had tools allowing users to browse from a vast selection of Shoutcast streams for listening. I found some articles suggesting that these features may no longer be available, due to changes with Shoutcast.

Are there any media players that are updated to work with Shoutcast, not just allowing playing of the audio, but browsing of the stations?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a "media player" (it doesn't integrate to existing audio player GUI), but a Japanese Linux distro [linuxBean](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/linuxbean/) has a [Radio Tuner](https://bitbucket.org/aztake/triforium/src/79c136729aeba19b9306ae82c9cbd712324c30cf/usr+local+bin/bean_radio?at=master) shell script that lets you browse and search radio stations from SHOUTcast. After you select a station this tool will launch the default music player.

This tool depends on bash (this is a bash shell script), wget (for downloading SHOUTcast page), yad (for showing its GUI), jq (for parsing responces from SHOUTcast website), xsel (Optional, for copying info to the clipboard), streamripper (Optional, for recording the stream).

These dependencies can be installed in Ubuntu 14.04 and its variants (such as Kubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17.*) with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install jq xsel streamripper
```

yad is available via [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yad
```

This tool's GUI is written in Japanese, so I made an [unofficial English translation here](https://gist.github.com/NullNoname/5886332a31b2b406e2da).
You can download and run it with the following commands:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NullNoname/5886332a31b2b406e2da/raw/eae1acf243b5b696e393df0dbdc741433ee2d750/bean_radio_en
chmod +x bean_radio_en
./bean_radio_en
```

Comment: This should get more OSS love. Thanks for the translation brother.